# How to convert an AudioBuffer to a mp3 file?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audio-processing, audiobuffer

Is there an easy way of doing that, or do I need to interleave the channels and create a `DataView` that contains a specific header format as well as the interleaved data?

Comment: Is requirement specifically to create an `.mp3` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, this is not possible on the web platform. We want to overhaul the decoding and encoding primitives so that they work both in real-time (like `MediaRecorder`, today) and offline (say, encode an `OfflineAudioContext`). We haven't even started standardizing this, we're working on finishing up the Web Audio API.

However, thanks to emscripten, it's quite easy to do regardless, use a version of `libmp3lame` compiled to javascript of `wasm`, such as https://github.com/higuma/mp3-lame-encoder-js.

I would recommend getting `ArrayBuffer`s from your `AudioBuffer`, using `getChannelData(channelIndex)`, transfer that to a web worker (without copying, so it's fast), and post the encoded blob back to the main thread when it's done.

Comment: I have tried that project on Github and it is very slow, especially on mobile. You would think that it's only natural that if you have a decode method on the audio context, there is an encode method.

Comment: I have seen good reports about lamejs. It is an MP3 encoder written in Javascript (so no wasm which for me has resulted in it aborting because of virtual memory issues): https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs